# Celery use wrong python version

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a Django project, and I want to use Celery. I've installed Celery for python3, and then I run this command : `sudo celery -A myApp worker -l info`

But in the log, I see that it's Celery of python2.7 which is used : `File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`

Any idea how for me to use the Celery installed for python3 ?

Comment: what does `which celery` produce? And `head -n1 $(which celery)`?

Comment: You probably just installed `celery` for `Python 2`, you might want to try and change `sudo pip install celery` to something like `sudo pip3 install celery`.

Comment: how do you know you installed celery for python3? How did you install it?

Comment: @WayneWerner when I run `which celery`I have this : /usr/local/bin/celery

And I know that I have installed celery for python 3 because I've done `pip uninstall celery`and `pip3 install celery`

And, maybe it could help, in the end I have `ImportError: No module named django.conf`. But it still try tu use celery in the python2.7 folder :/

Comment: And `head -n /usr/local/bin/celery`?

Comment: When I use the command `head -n /usr/local/bin/celery` , I have this answer : `head: illegal line count -- /usr/local/bin/celery`

Comment: Let's not forget that virtual environments were invented precisely to make management of issues like this easier. Also, it helps to know how the shell decides which program to run (the `$PATH` environment variable). Activating a virtualenv automatically puts its `bin` directory at the front of the path, meaning that if there's a program with the right name as a part of the virtualenv that's the one that will (generally) execute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, thanks to @Wayne I've found the solution.

First, use this command to see where the head of celery is : `head -n 10 /usr/local/bin/celery`
For myself, this is what I get :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'celery==3.1.23','console_scripts','celery'
__requires__ = 'celery==3.1.23'
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('celery==3.1.23', 'console_scripts', 'celery')()
    )
```

I see that the first shebang (`#!/usr/bin/python`) use the wrong python version.

Then, I've changed the first shebang : `#!/usr/bin/env python3` and save the file. Now celery point to python3.